# Play music by Python

Tags: python, subprocess

```
import subprocess as sp
sp.call("afplay","music.mp3")
```

This is my code for playing music in Python but it gives me the error that is given below:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-a28808f89c81> in <module>()
      1 import subprocess as sp
----> 2 sp.call("afplay","3peg")

/home/pir4t3/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/subprocess.pyc in call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
    166     retcode = call(["ls", "-l"])
    167     """
--> 168     return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
    169 
    170 

/home/pir4t3/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/subprocess.pyc in __init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags)
    337 
    338         if not isinstance(bufsize, (int, long)):
--> 339             raise TypeError("bufsize must be an integer")
    340 
    341         if mswindows:

TypeError: bufsize must be an integer
```

Any ideas?

or Any other ideas to play music (mp3 file) on Linux by Python

Comment: you need: `sp.call(["afplay","3peg"])`  (you have the example in your traceback: `166     retcode = call(["ls", "-l"])`)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set a variable for it or else it won't work. Try doing this:

```
play = sp.call(["afplay", "music.mp3"])
```

Hope this works!